# Set specified width for column

Tags: tables, tabulary, column-width

I am trying to make a table and want to set the first column with specified width, namely 1 inch. I have seen some relevant solutions, but they basically use `\textwidth`. Therefore I am looking if there is some simple direct solution to assign the width as 1 inch.

Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            1, 1 & 2, 1\\
            1, 2 & 2, 2
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried `p{1in}` instead `l`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `p{1in}` instead of `l`.

In the following code I added `|` to get vertical lines for marking the printed columns.

Please see the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \begin{tabular}{|p{1in}|l|} % <====================================
            1, 1 & 2, 1\\
            1, 2 & 2, 2
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Btw I find it interesting that one can use the command \newline with "p{...}" but not "l".

Comment: @Salomo Well, `l` supposes a short column entry, which needs no linebreaking. `p` is build to be able to break lines ...

Comment: May I ask a follow-up question, if I want the last column use up all the remaining space, is there something like "p{}"?

Comment: @Salomo Then you should use environment `tabularx`, see documentation on your terminal/console with `texdoc tabularx`.